# Software to autoconnect bluetooth device on win7 or win10 after system start

Tags: windows, automation, bluetooth

Is there any software I can use to autoconnect my Windows PC (Win7 or Win10) after a system start to my bluetooth speakers?

I am using bluetooth speakers with my PC which is working fine, but after every restart of my PC I have to manually connect to the speakers again. I'm using the CSR Harmony Bluetooth-Software-Stack Version 2.1.63.0 on Win 7.

I want the following behaviour:

1. I start my Windows
2. My bluetooth speakers get automatically connected without clicking any button manually

I'm fine with installing batch script, autohotkey or whatever works.